# NoMethodError in Login#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

This is my controller for the app.

```
private
def app_params
    params.require(:login).permit(:name, :surname, :username, :password, :email)
end
def new 
    @login = Login.new app_params
    unless app_params.nil?
        @login.save

    end
end
def show 
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
def create
    @login = Login.new(params[:login])
    if @login.save
        flash[:success] = "Saved"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Code for the new_login_path is:

<%= form_for Login.new do |f| %>
 so on..

The error message it shows is:

undefined method `logins_path' for #<#:0x007fba3824be28>

Comment: Could you paste your `/config/routes.rb file`

Comment: Why not use <%= form_for @login do |f| %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the action above `private`. every method you define below `private` is treated as private method. while the controller actions need to be publicly accessible. So Define the action above the `private` keyword.

```
def new 
  @login = Login.new app_params
  unless app_params.nil?
    @login.save
  end
end
def show 
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
def create
  @login = Login.new(params[:login])
  if @login.save
    flash[:success] = "Saved"
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

private
def app_params
  params.require(:login).permit(:name, :surname, :username, :password, :email)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `logins_path` method should be generated automatically by Rails based on the contents of your `config/routes.rb` file.  Do you have a line like this?

```
resources :logins
```

After you fix your routing issue, you'll want to move your action methods above the `private` declaration as in Manoj Monga's answer.